# Is there a better solution for this?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I'm sure there should be a more creative way to solve this ... Anyone interested?

Q: Given the following code, determine the range of possible values for “a” :

```
  x = random_int(1,6)

  y = random_int(1,6)

  z = random_int(1,6)

  a = x + y + z
```

My Answer:

```js
var x, y, z, a;
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  a = x + y + z;
  range.push(a);
}
var min = Math.min.apply(null, range),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, range);

document.write("The range is between " + min + " and " + max);
```

Comment: Well, I can't see how the minimum will ever be different to 3. What are you trying to do exactly.

Comment: Where's the psuedo-code?

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm to solve it. Obviously I know the answer!

Comment: Solve what. The minimum of 3*1 and maximum of 3*6, as far as I can see, although you might get less than 18, if you do it enough times.

Comment: Given the code means that the ranges are given.  Resulting range is just (sum mimima(ranges)..sum  maxima(ranges).  What are you trying to ask here?

Answer (score 0):

This is all the code :

```
document.write("The range is between 3 and 18");
```

because minimum is when all the randoms are 1 so it would be

```
x = min(random_int(1,6)) = 1
y = min(random_int(1,6)) = 1
z = min(random_int(1,6)) = 1
```

so

```
a = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

and maximum will be like this :

```
x = max(random_int(1,6)) = 6
y = max(random_int(1,6)) = 6
z = max(random_int(1,6)) = 6
```

so

```
a = 6 + 6 + 6 = 18
```